# Working with static and dynamic data in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

On my page I show the first and last name of a person using labels.

It is then possible to edit the first and last name in a couple of input-fields. I only want to update the labels, when the user hits save, but when updating the input-fields, the labels update as well. How do I make sure, the labels are only updated on save ?

I have created a plunker here to show the issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/WSpZeifClaIL81GUI2eP?p=preview

Note that the labels change when the input is updated.

thanks

Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/i0JUOm?p=preview).

Just clone the object you are working on with `angular.copy`.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.data={first_name:"John", last_name:"Doe"};
        $scope.user=angular.copy($scope.data);
        $scope.staticUser=$scope.data;
```

This will create a deep copy of the object and therefore you won't be referencing the same object.  The rest of your code works as is.